# SQLite Insert Query trims 0 as the first character of an inserted string

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I have an insert query, it adds the contacts on the database. However, I have a problem with inserting a string that has "0" as its first character.

For example I input this: 09127400049
  It will now be saved as:
    9127400049

```
public void addEmergencyContacts(String name, long number, String email, String relationship) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("NAME", name);
    cv.put("NUMBER", number);
    cv.put("EMAIL", email);
    cv.put("RELATIONSHIP", relationship);

    this.getWritableDatabase().insertOrThrow("ELSA_EMERGENCY_CONTACTS", "", cv);
}
```

Here's how I insert contacts

```
controller.addEmergencyContacts(emergencyContactET.getText().toString(), Long.parseLong(emergencyNumberET.getText().toString()), emergencyEmailET.getText().toString(), relationship);
```

Do you know any solutions or suggestion there

Comment: You're parsing the phone number as `long` and sending it. Once parced the phone number won't be `0009123` but will be `9123`, unless you format it differnetly when putting it in the `cv` variable. Put a breakpoint on this line `cv.put("NUMBER", number);` and check what value `number` has

Comment: Do you have any idea to insert the 0 characters?

Comment: Please add the create table query. As Nikola told you, you're parsing the phone number as long before inserting it, and perhaps also with the table structure. You have to handle it as a String for the whole

Comment: Phone number should be stored and manipulated as String... and not as long... So, change your database and your code to represent phone numbe as String and not as Long).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert the 0 character you will need to do the following:-

- Define the **NUMBER** column with a column type of **TEXT**, if it is not already defined as type TEXT.
- Change the **addEmergencyContacts** method's signature so that the **2nd** parameter is **String**

  - i.e. change `public void addEmergencyContacts(String name, long number, String email, String relationship) {.....` to **`public void addEmergencyContacts(String name, String number, String email, String relationship) {.....`**
- Change each call to **`addEmergencyContacts`** to pass the value for the 2nd parameter as a string ensuring that the leading 0 is included in that string.
- either

  - Delete the App's data or
  - Uninstall the App
- rerun the App.

---

The reasoning is that in order to be flexible and efficient SQLite :-

- has flexible column types
- allows most columns to store data of any type
- uses rules that attempt to store data in as few bytes as possible.

Rather than go into great detail here's a link detailing the factors [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html).